# how i get img src from a particular class from other website url php or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In **website A** I want to fetch an image from **website B** which has **class xyz**. So how can I do that with PHP or JS or JQuery?

Website A is the place where I want the image.

Website B:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>wdsadbsabd sad sa djsa dkj sakj dsa d asd jksa dkj asd ksa dkj asdjk </p>
    <p>
        <img src="" id="abc" />
        <img src="dsad.jpg" class="xyz" />
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you cant access DOM of other domain for security reasons

Comment: use `file_get_contents` and `DOMDocument` / `XPath` - straightforward stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://www.yoursitelink.com/',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
        var html = data;
        $("#img").attr('src');
      }
    });
```

also set the header to get the data from any other url.Hope this will help you.